# How to pass object as a parameter in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object, parameters

I found a few questions on here relating to my question but didn't exactly get the answer I was looking for. I am wanting to do something like this, similar to what jQuery often does:

```
createCSS("mystyle.css", {
    media: "screen",
    type: "text/css"
});
```

I tried this to accomplish what I want but it's not working:

```
var prop = {
    media: '',
    type: ''
};

function createCSS(href, prop) {
    var anchor = document.createElement("link");
    anchor.setAttribute("href", href);
    anchor.setAttribute("media", prop.media);
    anchor.setAttribute("type", prop.type);

    if(typeof anchor != "undefined") {
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild( anchor );
    }
}
```

Now, I know I could just create single multiple parameters like `createCSS("mystyle.css", "screen", "text/css");` but I don't like that, the other way looks cooler.

Plenty new to javascript so any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to just eliminate the var prop = { ... } declaration? And test if everything else works...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have to declare/initialize `var prop`. Your function looks fine, just call it passing an object as `prop`, as in your own example:

```
createCSS("mystyle.css", {
    media: "screen",
    type: "text/css"
});
```

If the intention with the `var prop` part was to avoid assigning `undefined` to the attributes, you need a little tweak *inside the function*:

```
function createCSS(href, prop) {
    prop = (typeof prop !== "object") ? {} : prop;
    prop.media = prop.media || 'screen';  // default media will be screen
    prop.href = prop.href || 'text/css';  // default type will be text/css
    // rest of code
}
```

---

Some minor improvements I'd suggest:

- Your variable `anchor` does not contain an anchor (`<a>`) element. Why not call it `link`?
- You don't seem to need the `if(typeof anchor != "undefined")` conditional. since you're creating the element a few lines above, that variable will never be undefined. You can skip the `if` and `appendChild` directly.

Comment: Oh, wow. Okay. I would think `prop.media` and `prop.type` would render undefined. Thanks!

Comment: you can predefine `prop`, but in that case don't forget to include it into the call: `createCSS("mystyle.css", prop)`

Comment: You already had it and didn't know it :). Also: I just added a couple of suggestions that may help you improve your code.

Comment: @Bfavaretto wow! Thanks. I like it. And thanks for letting me know about the unnecessary conditional statement. I found it by sniffing around online and didn't really like the looks of it anyway. Good suggestions, too.

Answer (score 4):

"I tried this to accomplish what I want but it's not working"

The way you pass your object is fine. Although there are some interesting choices in the function, it does what you are asking. However, have you inspected the link you create? It lacks the `rel` directive which is a requirement.

You may want to change your function to this:

```
function createCSS(href, prop) {
 var anchor = document.createElement("link");
 anchor.setAttribute("href", href);
 anchor.setAttribute("media", prop.media);
 anchor.setAttribute("type", prop.type);
 anchor.setAttribute("rel", prop.rel);
 document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild( anchor );
}

var prop = { 
 media: "screen",
 type: "text/css",
 rel: "stylesheet"
}

createCSS( "mystyle.css", prop );
```

Comment: @TravisJ Thanks! It actually took me like 10 minutes to figure out why `test.css` wasn't working, and it was because of the `rel`. +1